# Storing items when having multiple requests in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an **item** object that i need to get out of the method **phoneParse** and load its values along with other values i already loaded

Am trying to get the phone number out from the callback function and add it to the loader that way when ever i generate my json or csv file i get the data from

```
loader.add_css("features", '.offer-features__item::text')
loader.add_value('url', response.url)
```

along with the data for the number.

How can i implement something like that ?

```
import scrapy
import time
import json


from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

from otomoto.items import OtomotoItem


def filter_out_array(x):
    x = x.strip()
    return None if x == '' else x


class OtomotoCarLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    features_out = MapCompose(filter_out_array)


class OtomotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'otomoto'
    start_urls = ['https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for car_page in response.css('.offer-title__link::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(car_page, self.parse_car_page)

        for next_page in response.css('.next.abs a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
########################## the function added to get the phone number ################

    def parse_number(self, response):

        #raw_data = response.url.body
        #for params in raw_data:
        number_id = response.xpath('//a[@data-path="multi_phone"]/@data-id').extract()
        print("NUMBER", number_id)
        number_id = list(dict.fromkeys(number_id))
        #number_id = response.css('a::attr(data-id)' and 'a::attrdata-path="multi_phone")
        print("NUMBER", number_id)
        return number_id

        #loader.add('number', number)
################################################################################

    def phoneParse(self, response):
        print("Res",response)
        item = response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
        print(type(item))
        print(item)
    # HERE YOU NEED TO ITERATE IF YOU NEED ALL NUMBERS... but i think mostly they are the same, sometimes there are 2
        json_acceptable_string = item[0].replace("'", "\"")
        number_item_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
        print("RES2",number_item_dict["value"].replace(" ","")) # THERE IT IS AS STRING
        time.sleep(10)
        return item
    def parse_car_page(self, response):
        number_id = self.parse_number(response)
        for id in number_id:
            phone_url = "https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/" + id + '/0/'
            print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA URL : "+phone_url)
            request = scrapy.Request(phone_url, callback=self.phoneParse)
            print(request)
        yield request

            #number = response.body
            #print('NUMBER',number)

            #<span class="objectBox objectBox-string">"725 169 377"</span>
            #exit()
        property_list_map = {
            'Marka pojazdu': 'brand',
            'Model pojazdu': 'model',
            'Rok produkcji': 'year',

        }
        loader = OtomotoCarLoader(OtomotoItem(), response=response)

        for params in response.css('.offer-params__item'):

            property_name = params.css(
                '.offer-params__label::text').extract_first().strip()
            if property_name in property_list_map:
                css = params.css('div::text').extract_first().strip()
                if css == '':
                    css = params.css('a::text').extract_first().strip()

                loader.add_value(property_list_map[property_name], css)

        loader.add_css('features', '.offer-features__item::text')
        loader.add_value('url', response.url)
        #loader.add_value('number', response.number)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: you have 1 JSON object which you want to fill then once scraping is done yield it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do but normally you  can use `for`-loop with `yield` inside - ie `for number in list_of_numbers: yield {"number": number}`

Comment: you have to better describe problem. Maybe show some example data and expected result.

Comment: hey @furas thank you for your responsoe,i edited my original anwser am trying to get out of a callback function and add the number to the loader

Comment: Please, [make your example minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems you need `Request(..., meta=...)` to send data from `parse_car_page` to `parse_phone`  and in `parse_phone` use `yield` with all data. So it works in different direction - not get data from `parse_phone` to `parse`/`parse_car_page`  but send data from `parse`/`parse_car_page` to  `parse_phone`  and continue scraping data to yield all data in `parse_phone`

Comment: eventually you would have to use module `urllib` or `request` to get data from url `.../multi_phone/...` and then you get it at once. You can't get result from scrapy `Request` because it doesn't run it at once but it sends request to queue and scrapy runs this request later - when it has free worker in sheduler. See [scrapy architecture](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

Comment: can you please write answer where you clarify how could i implement what you said , thank you very much

Comment: I'm working on full working example which everyone could run (PL: pracuje na wpełni diałającym przykładzie, ktorego każdy będzie mógł uruchomić)

Comment: oh thank you so much I can't  wait to see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scrapy` uses sheduler to run requests so when you use `Request()` then it puts it in queue and it loads page later (when it has free workers, etc. See: [architecture](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)) so it doesn't run it directly and you can't get results from `parsePhoto` into `parse_car_page`

You have to send data from `parse_car_page` to `parsePhoto`:

- in `parse_car_page` parse all data which are on page
- in `parse_car_page` use `Request(..., meta=... )` to send these data (or `loader`) to `parsePhoto`

  ```
  yield scrapy.Request(phone_url, callback=self.phone_parse, meta={'loader': loader})
  ```
- in `parsePhoto` get these data

  ```
  loader = response.meta['loader']
  ```
- in `parsePhoto` scrapes number and `yield` all data

---

**BTW:** in `meta=` you can use almost any key(s) - but some have special meaning: [Request.meta special keys](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-meta)

---

Full working code.

You can put it one file and run `python script.py` without creating project. And it will save data in `output.csv`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
import json
import time

class OtomotoItem(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    model = scrapy.Field()
    year = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    number = scrapy.Field()
    features = scrapy.Field()


def filter_out_array(x):
    x = x.strip()
    return None if x == '' else x


class OtomotoCarLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    features_out = MapCompose(filter_out_array)


class OtomotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'otomoto'
    start_urls = ['https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for car_page in response.css('.offer-title__link::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(car_page, self.parse_car_page)

        for next_page in response.css('.next.abs a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)

    def parse_car_page(self, response):

        loader = OtomotoCarLoader(OtomotoItem(), response=response)

        property_list_map = {
            'Marka pojazdu': 'brand',
            'Model pojazdu': 'model',
            'Rok produkcji': 'year',
        }

        for params in response.css('.offer-params__item'):

            property_name = params.css('.offer-params__label::text').extract_first().strip()

            if property_name in property_list_map:
                css = params.css('div::text').extract_first().strip()

                if css == '':
                    css = params.css('a::text').extract_first().strip()

                loader.add_value(property_list_map[property_name], css)

        loader.add_css('features', '.offer-features__item::text')
        loader.add_value('url', response.url)

        number_id = self.parse_number(response)
        print('number_id:', len(number_id), '|', number_id)

        for id in number_id:
            phone_url = "https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/" + id + '/0/'
            # use `meta=` to send data to `photo_parse`
            yield scrapy.Request(phone_url, callback=self.phone_parse, meta={'loader': loader})

    def parse_number(self, response):
        number_id = response.xpath('//a[@data-path="multi_phone"]/@data-id').extract()
        print("NUMBER [before]:", number_id)

        number_id = list(set(number_id))  # you can use `set()` to get unique values
        print("NUMBER [after] :", number_id)

        return number_id

    def phone_parse(self, response):
        print("[phone_parse] response:", response)

        # get data from `parse_car_page`
        loader = response.meta['loader']

        item = response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
        print('[phone_parse] item:', type(item), item)

        json_data = json.loads(item[0])
        print('[phone_parse] json:', json_data)

        number = json_data["value"].replace(" ","")
        print("'[phone_parse] number:", number) # THERE IT IS AS STRING

        # add new data to loader
        loader.add_value('number', number)

        yield loader.load_item()

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(OtomotoSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: thank you for the time and the effort you put into this response it was clear and easy to understand even for some one just starting with scrapy like me.

Comment: BTW: I keep some my examples from Stackoverflow on GitHub: examples for [scrapy](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/scrapy) and examples for different pages [scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)

Comment: i will definitely check them out thank you very much

Comment: @Max what is the problem ? I can get `Szczegóły` without problem - but without using  `loader`. Now I would need Fields in `Item` to use `loade.add_value(name, value)`. I don't want to add it in one column like `features`

Comment: thank you for your response @furas i was able to solve the issue , i also manged to extracted the address the only problem am having is spliting the extracted data into 2 columns [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595620/split-on-comma-using-python-and-scrapy?noredirect=1#comment110696213_62595620] i tried asking here if you could take a look it would be very much appreciated