# Split on comma using python and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Am using scrapy to extract data from a certain website, I have a field am extracting that returns both the city and the region I want to be able to split the returned data on the comma and store the first part of it inside the city field and second part of it in the region field
The code am using to extract the data :

```
 loader.add_css('region','.seller-box__seller-address__label::text')
```

the output of the data is : a column named region with for example this value :

Elbląg, Warmińsko-mazurskie

the desired output would be two columns the first being city with the value of : Elbląg and region with the value of : Warmińsko-mazurskie

UPDATE :

apprently the loader can take an additional arrgument for regular expressions : i was able to split the data by passing

`loader.add_css('region','.seller-box__seller-address__label::text',re='([^,]+)$')`

This will remove everything before the comma.

Comment: Are you looking for string split ``"Elbląg, Warmińsko-mazurskie".split(",")``

Comment: along with the split am looking for a way to store the splited data into two diffrent columns as i mentioned the first splited part need to go in the city column and the second needs to go in the region column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `loader` has special method for split value into two fields.

Normally I would do

```
text = response.css('.seller-box__seller-address__label::text').extract_first().strip()

city, region = tex.split(', ') 

loader.add_value('city', city)
loader.add_value('region', region)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, i found that the loader can take a regular expression by passing re= along with the other arguments, but this definitely works too!

Comment: if you can resolve it with `re=` then you can add example code as answer. It can be useful for other users.

Comment: yes thank you, i will update my original question with that approach

Comment: you can put it as answer